# SQL - First Select with Score than with NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I need to Select and Union Records sorted by an activity score. I have a solution that works for all Records that have a score. Now I need to fill the selection with records that do not have a score and where the data is empty.
The following statement works for Records with score and needs to be extended:

```
SELECT 
Name, Activityscore
FROM 
(SELECT
TOP 2084 * FROM [Table] 
WHERE Email like '%@test%' AND Activityscore in ( 1, 2, 3, 4)
order by Activityscore desc ) t1
UNION 
SELECT
Name, Activityscore
```

```html
    SELECT 
    Name, Activityscore
    FROM 
    (SELECT
    TOP 2084 * FROM [Table] 
    WHERE Email like '%@test%' AND Activityscore in ( 1, 2, 3, 4) OR Email like '%@test%' AND Activityscore is NULL
    order by Activityscore desc ) t1
    UNION 
    SELECT
    Name, Activityscore
    FROM
    (SELECT
    TOP 14000 * FROM [Table] 
    WHERE Email NOT like '%@test%' AND Email NOT like '%@test2%' AND Activityscore in ( 1, 2, 3, 4) OR Email NOT like '%@test%' AND Email NOT like '%@test2%' AND Activityscore is NULL
    order by Activityscore desc ) t2
```

```
FROM
(SELECT
TOP 14000 * FROM [Table] 
WHERE Email NOT like '%@test%' AND Email NOT like '%@test2%' AND Activityscore in ( 1, 2, 3, 4)
order by Activityscore desc ) t2
```

Edit:

We have a List with User. Some of them have a Score some have not. The goal is to select first all with a score descending from 4 to 3 to 2 to 1. This function is working with the sample snippet. Now I need to fill up those records with records that do not have any score assigned. For example: I have a table with 10.000 records. 5.000 have a score (1-4) and 5.000 have none. Now I need to select 8.000, so the statement needs to select first all 5.000 with score and the choose the rest (3.000) randomly without score. Hope that clears the use case.

The following seem to bring the expected results:

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That query is product specific.

Comment: Sample data would go a long way here.

Comment: HI Tim what exactly do you mean?

Comment: he means add some sample data so that we can see what your data looks like and what you want it to look like so any solution can be tested and verified.

Comment: Can you please post some sample data and expected result

Answer (score 0):

What about this -

```
SELECT 
Name, Activityscore
FROM 
(SELECT
TOP 2084 * FROM [Table] 
WHERE Email like '%@test%' AND Activityscore in ( 1, 2, 3, 4, NULL, '')
order by Activityscore desc ) t1
UNION 
SELECT
Name, Activityscore
FROM
(SELECT
TOP 14000 * FROM [Table] 
WHERE Email NOT like '%@test%' AND Email NOT like '%@test2%' AND 
Activityscore in ( 1, 2, 3, 4, NULL, '')
order by Activityscore desc ) t2
```

Comment: This does not bring the expected Result but selects only 6.500 records.

Comment: This does not bring the expected solution as well.

Comment: this does not select Records without Score

Answer (score 0):

I tried as well the following without getting the expected re

```
SELECT 
Name, Activityscore
FROM 
(SELECT
TOP 2084 * FROM [Table] 
WHERE Email like '%@test%' AND Activityscore in ( 1, 2, 3, 4) OR Activityscore is NULL
order by Activityscore desc ) t1
UNION 
SELECT
Name, Activityscore
FROM
(SELECT
TOP 14000 * FROM [Table] 
WHERE Email NOT like '%@test%' AND Email NOT like '%@test2%' AND Activityscore in ( 1, 2, 3, 4) OR Activityscore is NULL
order by Activityscore desc ) t2
```